# Why are the exhaust pipes design on the Ilyushin Il-2 not very popular?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, piston-engine

This is a piece of [this image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ilyushin_IL-2_Sturmovik,_Central_Air_Force_Museum,_Monino.JPG)

[image]

Note the circled region. Movies often show exhaust fumes coming from those pipes when the engine is started. So I assume these are actual exhaust pipes.
This design doesn't appear very often, especially in modern piston engine airplanes. Why is this the case?

Comment: I think a lot of it has to do with noise. This design was popular on propeller driven fighter (military) aircraft that didn't care about noise.

Comment: also, this aircraft has a V12 engine ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikulin_AM-38 ) like the Merlin in the Spitfire, so the layout makes sense. with radial engines and flat opposed engines, this type of exhaust configuration wouldn't make sense

Comment: Compare to other aircraft of the same period, I think you'll find it very common indeed.

Answer (score 5):

This engine is about 10 times more powerful than a modern average piston engine. With such power you get some useful thrust from exhaust power directly. This design helps to recover it. With a small SEP, noise and keeping exhaust smoke away from the cabin probably is more important. And it's not true that it's not popular. It's popular with single engine turbines. [image]
<sup>Source: Wikimedia (click for link)</sup>

Comment: Or multi-engine turbines, for that matter.

Comment: I don't actually think there was much thrust to extract. The key point was not creating resistance inside the exhaust pipes themselves.

Answer (score 5):

It was popular at that time. All the [Curtiss P-40 Warhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_P-40_Warhawk), [North American P-51 Mustang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_P-51_Mustang), [Hawker Hurricane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Hurricane), [Supermarine Spitfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermarine_Spitfire), [Hawker Tempest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Tempest), [Messerschmitt Bf109](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Bf_109) and many more had similar.

That kind of exhaust was tied to the engine, a water-cooled 2-line 12-cylinder [(V-12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V12_engine#Later_V12s_in_aviation) and later some 4-line 24-cylinder ([H-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_engine#Aircraft_engines) or [X-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_engine)) engines. So there was a row of cylinders on each side and each had its own exhaust pipe as short as possible to minimize its resistance.

Since then, anything with more than 6 cylinders was replaced by turbines and all the smaller engines are air-cooled, because in GA aircraft the simplicity of air-cooled engine is more useful than the slightly lower drag of water-cooled one (navy preferred air-cooled even in fighters for the same reason). And air-cooled engines generally have their exhaust pipes lead into the cooling air stream and thus hidden under the cowling.

Comment: Basically anything with a V-12 had more or less that setup. Anything with a Merlin or other RR engine, all the Allison and Packard V-12s in the US, all the V-12s in Soviet and German fighters... the list goes on. Pick a V-12 engined fighter from WW2 and you'll see this exhaust style.

Comment: @egid, what surprises me is that there didn't seem to be any V-10, V-14, V-16 and other sizes. It was all V-12 and later some H-24. They exist in other domains, but not in aviation.

Comment: @egid, [Mosquito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Mosquito) seems like a notable exception with the exhaust covered by some kind of common cowling.

Comment: Not in photos I've seen? Maybe the inboard pilot's side has a flash hider or something... [example](http://airpigz.com/blog/2012/10/3/coolpix-avspecs-de-havilland-mosquito-in-the-air-bravo.html)

Comment: @egid, many of the pictures on WP have it. Not all though.

Comment: Yeah, maybe related to nighttime bombing use? They used Mosquitos as pathfinders, perhaps they wanted to minimize warning at low altitude?

Comment: @egid, probably. After all, in a sense it was the first stealth aircraft.

Comment: I believe they were called flame dampers.  Exhaust flames were visible at night.

Comment: I only see five pipes, not six.

Comment: @sharptooth, [This picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-2#/media/File:Ilyushin_Il-2_Lebyazhye_3.JPG) shows there are 6, but the last one is more straight and very close to the fifth, so they can't be distinguished from the angle the image you posted was made from.